# Why PHP sleep() blocks Postgresql query?

Tags: php, postgresql, sockets, asynchronous, sleep

We have encountered a problem with PHP `pg_send_query` and `pg_connection_busy` while upgrading from Centos 6 to Centos 7.

```
Postgresql: 9.6.3 compiled from source
PHP: 5.6.16 / 7.1 compiled from source / package rpm
Linux: Centos 7
```

**(A)** No problem without sleep:

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM idx.idx_indeks ORDER BY indeks";
$DBconn=pg_connect("host=168.21.5.1 dbname=dbprod");
$s=pg_send_query($DBconn,$sel);
$res = pg_get_result($DBconn);
```

It takes around 2 s to execute the query and finish the script.

**(B)**
Adding sleep makes it run much longer:

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM idx.idx_indeks ORDER BY indeks";
$DBconn=pg_connect("host=168.21.5.1 dbname=dbprod");
$s=pg_send_query($DBconn,$sel);

while(pg_connection_busy($DBconn)) {
        usleep(10000);
}

$res = pg_get_result($DBconn);
```

Now it takes over 60 s to execute query and finish the script.
During running the php script the SQL query in `pg_stat_activity` has status active, and stays active as long as the php script is running.

It doesn't matter if I work on two different severs (one with PHP and the second with Postgresl) or if all is set up on the localhost.

**On Centos 6 with the same PostgreSql and PHP (A) and (B) cases takes the same time - around 2 s.**

**(B.2)**

But if i connect do database through socket it also takes over 60 s to exectue(!):

```
Linux: Centos 6


$sel = "SELECT * FROM idx.idx_indeks ORDER BY indeks";
$DBconn=pg_connect("dbname=dbprod");  // Socket connection
$s=pg_send_query($DBconn,$sel);
$res = pg_get_result($DBconn);

while(pg_connection_busy($DBconn)) {
        usleep(10000);
}

$res = pg_get_result($DBconn);
```

**(C)**

Today I found if I use `pg_consume_input` then on Centos7 there is no problem. 
The script is again running 2 s as I expect. But I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM idx.idx_indeks ORDER BY indeks";
$DBconn=pg_connect("host=168.21.5.1 dbname=dbprod");
$s=pg_send_query($DBconn,$sel);

while(pg_connection_busy($DBconn)) {
    pg_consume_input($DBconn);
    usleep(10000);
}

$res = pg_get_result($DBconn);
```

I suppose there problem could be in socket handling in new Centos. It looks like using sleep() in php blocks somehow executing sql in postgresql in different process.